# error Refused to execute script, because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: 8, migrations

When migrated my site from localhost to webserver. I see an error in chromeconsole. I used git clone to transfer my site.

> Refused to execute script from http://mydomain because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

Mysite is unformatted.
Theme bartik, core drupal-8.2.5

It's running smooth on localhost.

I contacted serversupport, they say it's a debug problem and not a server problem.

there is an refer in the stylesheet to ojqe8x, but is empty, how to solve this?

```
<title>mysite | mysite</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joehoe/mysite/?ojqe8x" media="all" />
```

Edit:

on this domain http://pcwebber.nl/alex/lkch/

I get this error Refused to execute script from 'http://pcwebber.nl/alex/lkch/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the `ojqe8x`. This is just a unique token to make sure browsers download a new version of the stylesheet once it has changed. (To prevent browsers from serving cached stylesheets). Your real problem is that there is no filename. You should see something like `/joehoe/mysite/style.css?ojqe8x`. Now it is probably linking to a webpage, also explaining the `text/html` MIME type. Try clearing the site caches an see where this stylesheet is coming from...

Comment: Hi, I cleared the cache<link rel="stylesheet" href="/joehoe/mysite/sites/default/files/css/css_Z5jMg7P_bjcW9iUzujI7oaechMyxQTUqZhHJ_aYSq04.css?ojqox6" media="print" />

Comment: the sheet is coming from `sites/default/files/css/css_Z5jMg7P_bjc‌​W9iUzujI7oaechMyxQTU‌​qZhHJ_aYSq04.css?ojq‌​ox6`

Comment: Well, that looks way better.

Comment: Ok thnx, but how can I fix the error?

Comment: I thought your site referred to a non existing stylesheet. That should have been fixed by now. If not, please edit your question and explain your problem using real paths, etc...

Comment: Ok I thnx, put the real paths in the question again. I read this about Javascript and Tools Issues but is minimal 5 years old  so I think not related to drupal8? https://www.drupal.org/node/72561

Answer (score 6):

You are asking the wrong question....

When you look at your page's source code, you'll see this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/alex/lkch/?ojqox6" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/alex/lkch/?ojqox6" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/alex/lkch/sites/default/files/css/css_Z5jMg7P_bjcW9iUzujI7oaechMyxQTUqZhHJ_aYSq04.css?ojqox6" media="print" />
```

The last one is a real CSS file. The first two are not (those link to your front page). So your browser attempts to load a stylesheet, but is receiving your front page instead. That is what is triggering the error; The browser expects CSS and is instead served HTML.

The real question is, where do these 2 lines come from... And that is hard to tell, since everything in Drupal can do that.

Things you can try;

- Disable CSS aggregation in Administration > Configuration > Development (you want to enable this once you go live)
- Disable all non core modules (if any)
- Try a different theme

It could be something coming from a custom template as well.

Comment: Ok thnx I have to make all these changes on localhost? And transfer again?

Comment: Since localhost works, I would not touch that and make a backup of it ;) Try on the bad site.

Comment: Should you suggest in general to disable css agregation on localhost, while cleaning cache

Comment: Drupal usually works fine with it being enabled, but if you have to debug CSS or javascript it may help to turn it off.

Comment: Ok I disabled css aggregation and also  js. It's wokring now. Thank you. What effect could it have? And have  to be it always turned off now? Sorry to many questions

Comment: Aggregation bundles multiple files together, so the client has fewer requests for individual files, increasing the performance and making the page load faster. Disabling removes those benefits. Under normal circumstances you want this enabled. But I have no idea what causes this, probably a configuration difference between development and production servers or something. That is something only you can figure out ;)

Comment: Usually this means that Drupal failed to write those files. Check your status report, either your files folder is not writable or full. You do *not* want to have this setting disabled on production

Comment: Since the question is closed i'll just add this here for future googlers: As @Berdir mentions, this problem can arise when the public files folder is unavailable. In my docker setup the whole folder was missing by default. So check that /sites/default/files exists and have the right owner and permissions, and be sure to clear cache afterwards.

Comment: I also had this in Drupal 7.  A giveaway is also errors like 'The specified file temporary://file3Hl91E could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured' at the same time, which is again, as other commenters have mentioned, because the files folder and/or subdirectories are not fully writeable.  /admin/reports/dblog will give you the full, rather more helpful error message, including the full path of the file it's attempting to save.

Comment: This actually worked for me on my local--disabling the aggregation of css/js files. `drush -y config-set system.performance css.preprocess 0` & `drush -y config-set system.performance js.preprocess 0`. Then my local was working.

Comment: I got this because I had the wrong path (dash/underscore oops on my part). So, Drupal was serving a 404 message as HTML when the non-existent file was requested and, well, that's not JS so the browser correctly throws this error.

Comment: In addition to my earlier comment, another solution is adding  `$conf['file_temporary_path'] = '/tmp';` to settings.php